# Grails - service fetches old domain data

Tags: grails, groovy

I have the following domain model:

```
class Folder {
    User user

    Set files = []
    static hasMany = [files: File]

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
        files cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And i have a request that returns a list of files for a specific folder. Sometimes, subsequent calls give different results. The DB is updated and correct, so it seems that the service fetches cached data.

Is there really some kind of cache that could make this happen? How can i solve it?

Comment: When you say the db is updated, is it being updated by gorm?  If you have some other service running that gorm doesn't know about it could explain why you get stale data.  You can turn off caching.   http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#caching  Set it to off to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Only my app updates and queries the db (MySQL). I see that in my app use_query_cache is false and use_second_level_cache is true. But is it possible that the same app and same controller/service give different results in subsequent requests?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit difficult to answer your question without more details, but I can give you couple of common reasons for this behavior:

- If you are querying using Folder.get(id), then the query is bound to
  pick the object from the 2nd level cache (and not db) if there is one
  in the cache. If this is the case you should use dynamic finders,
  i.e.,

  ```
   Folder.findById(id)
  ```

  This will always fetch the new object from the db.
- While saving the folder object, you may consider flushing the
  hibernate session by passing the option flush: true in save method:

  ```
     folder.save(flush: true)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question than an answer, but I don't have the 50 reputation to comment, so I'll post it here. My apologies for breach of etiquette.

Take a look in `DataSource.groovy` at some hibernate caching options, what do you see for these values?

```
cache.use_second_level_cache
cache.use_query_cache
```

The default for the first one is true, and the default for the second one is false. If the query cache is turned on you may be inadvertently caching values which are persisted indefinitely.

Also, what is the query you're actually executing that is returning cached results?

How long do the results appear cached? A few minutes, hours, until restart? I've run into situations where results appeared to be cached for 30-60 seconds when I had default settings (that was using MySQL).

Last (whew), you could always try turning on the SQL logging in `Config.groovy` to see if database queries are actually being made or not. This will provide the queries as well as the bind variables.

```
debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
trace 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder'
```